# How to fix 'Process unexpectedly exit'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After update Android Studio 3.4 and using

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'`

could not run my app. When I try to run the error shows : Process unexpectedly exit.

Downgrade to
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

work perfectly. Please help how to run with `version 3.4.0`

Comment: did you try to invalidate cache and restart after upgrading the version?

Comment: Yes, but did not work

Comment: same problem but work 3.3.2

Answer (score 5):

Same happened to me, I don't know what's causing this, probably the Aapt2 3.4.0, so I fixed it adding this in project `build.gradle(:app)`:

```
android {
...
...
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
            config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
            }
        }
...
...
}
```

Comment: This is way too oddly specific for a generic error. Your solution will very likely cause more issues later.

Comment: Can you explain your code its solve my problem to but i didn't understand what this piece of code do...

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade minimum gradle supported version of corresponding gradle plugin version.

Upgrade your gradle version from your current version to 5.1.1.

You can can change your gradle version by clicking **Project Structure** icon from toolbar or use keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**. 
then select project and enter 5.1.1 or minimum supported version in gradle version.

For more info regarding upgrading gradle plugin and their corresponding version follow google documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: I already use 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`, 
but did not work

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. Gradle version 3.4.2 has some problem. Just change gradle version in your project: build.gradle file. Change version to 3.2.1.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding this in project build.gradle(:app):

```
android {
...
...
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
            config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
            }
        }
...
...
}
```